# Javascript countdown clock rounding

Tags: javascript, php, countdown

I have the following code to help count down the amount of money owed on a property however instead of displaying 9-10 decimal places, I am looking for it to round down to 2 decimal places....

Could someone offer some help?

```
<?php    
$secondsleft = strtotime('Dec 31, 2014') - time();
$left = $secondsleft-1556952;

$owed = $left*0.0088192178;
$totalowed = $owed+267608.76;
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function () {
    /* set your parameters(
    number to countdown from,
    pause between counts in milliseconds,
    function to execute when finished
    )
    */

    startCountDown( <? php echo $totalowed; ?> , 1000, myFunction);
}

function startCountDown(i, p, f) {
    // store parameters
    var pause = p;
    var fn = f;
    var owed;
    var owebb;
    // make reference to div
    var countDownObj = document.getElementById("countDown");
    if (countDownObj == null) {
        // error
        alert("div not found, check your id");
        // bail
        return;
    }
    countDownObj.count = function (i) {
        // write out count
        countDownObj.innerHTML = i;
        if (i == 0) {
            // execute function
            fn();
            // stop
            return;
        }
        setTimeout(function () {
            // repeat
            countDownObj.count(i - 0.009);
            countDownObj.Math.round(countDownObj)
            alert(countDownObj);
        },
        pause);
    }
    // set it going
    countDownObj.count(i);

}

function myFunction() {
    alert("Paid Off!");
}
</script>
```

Comment: Well `countDownObj.Math.round(countDownObj)` is a runtime error

Comment: opps, that was me messing around trying to figure it out..

Comment: @jonovision did you try my suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

I used this in one of my old projects. Basically transforms UNIX time into two decimal point "agos"...

```
var ago = val.modified_ago;
//
if (ago > 86400) {
    ago = Math.round((ago / 86400) * 100) / 100 + "d";
} else if (ago > 3600) {
    ago = Math.round((ago / 3600) * 100) / 100 + "h";
} else if (ago > 60) {
    ago = Math.round((ago / 60) * 100) / 100 + "m";
} else {
    ago = Math.round(ago * 100) / 100 + "s";
}
```

If you didn't understand the hint...

```
Math.round(num * 100) / 100 //for ROUNDING TO TWO DECIMAL POINTS!
```

Comment: He's not asking about counting down time, he's asking about counting down money.

Comment: @PeterOlson Genius, thanks for -1. But it makes no difference if you round time or money.

Answer (score 0):

Rounding javascript floats/decimal to fixed percision is done via `.toFixed()` method.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tofixed.asp

e.g.

```
var someNumber = 1.2345678;
alert (someNumber.toFixed(2)); // outputs 1.23
```